# How we check movie is 3d or not from filename using regex

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I have certain file in my folder

```
PARANORMAN_3D_hsbs_.mkv      
RunAllNight_Filmbank.mkv         
SHUTTER_ISLAND_airwave.mkv
THE_CHANGE_UP_airwave.mkv
The_Avenger_3D_Trailer1.mkv
moviename (year).3d.hsbs.mkv
moviename 3d sbs.mkv
moviename.3D-HTAB.mkv
moviename-3D.sbs-720p.mkv
jurassic_world_airwave_3D_hsb.mkv
```

As per kodi forum http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=173385

Any of the following terms in the file name should trigger 3D detection:

```
3DTAB,3D.TAB,HTAB,3DSBS,3D.SBS,HSBS
```

What I try

```
 <?php
    $pattern="(7F7|3DSBS|3D.SBS|HSBS|H.SBS|H-SBS| SBS |FULL-SBS|FULL.SBS|)";
    $file_name="PARANORMAN_3D_hsbs_.mkv";
    if (preg_match($pattern, $file_name)) {
        echo "A match was found.";
    } else {
        echo "A match was not found.";
    }
```

If file name is `PARANORMAN_3D_hsbs_` it gives `true` But if file name `PARANORMAN3Dhsbs` i want `false`. My code give me true in every condition

How we check these thing in my file name

Comment: My code is working the olny problen when filename is something like `PARANORMAN3D` it also give me true

Comment: I just what to check these words comes after any special charector

Comment: yes if file name is `PARANORMAN_3D_hsbs_` it gives true But if file name `PARANORMAN3Dhsbs` i want false. My code give me true in every condition Special charector are[.,_, ,~,(,)]

Comment: Special charector would be `[.,_, ,~,(,)] `

Comment: @hakre please check updated file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the alternation of the different words you want to match:

```
(7F7|3DSBS|3D.SBS|HSBS|H.SBS|H-SBS| SBS |FULL-SBS|FULL.SBS)
```

You then write in comments you don't want to match it wihtin words. You also name it that way, that it must follow after a special character but you can't clearly say what are all special characters.

A good working approach with regular expressions in that case is to make use of [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), a special anchor written as `\b`. You can just put it in front of your alternation:

```
(\b(7F7|3DSBS|3D.SBS|HSBS|H.SBS|H-SBS| SBS |FULL-SBS|FULL.SBS))
 ^^^                                                         ^
```

You can also make the alternation non-capturing as you don't need it to capture (see as well [Subpatterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) to understand the inner parenthesis):

```
(\b(?:7F7|3DSBS|3D.SBS|HSBS|H.SBS|H-SBS| SBS |FULL-SBS|FULL.SBS))
    ^^
```

And you perhaps want to [ignore case](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
(\b(?:7F7|3DSBS|3D.SBS|HSBS|H.SBS|H-SBS| SBS |FULL-SBS|FULL.SBS))i
                                                                 ^
```

If the anchor does not work in your case, you can replace it with the regular expression that matches any of your special characters, for example with a character class:

```
([_-](?:7F7|3DSBS|3D.SBS|HSBS|H.SBS|H-SBS| SBS |FULL-SBS|FULL.SBS))i
```

This will allow only after underscore or dash and won't allow any of the words in the alternation at the beginning of the filename any longer (which is probably even wanted in your case).

Or with your character class:

```
([._ ~,](?:7F7|3DSBS|3D.SBS|HSBS|H.SBS|H-SBS| SBS |FULL-SBS|FULL.SBS))i
```

Comment: Also please see [2. 3D detection - 2.3 Video filenames flags](http://kodi.wiki/view/3D#Video_filenames_flags) for detection by filename when it comes to KODI. It uses a much shorter regular expression pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot Just want to one thing onle what is the meaning of `?:7F7` ?

Comment: That is explained in subpattern http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php , it makes the group non-capturing. Capturing means you could extract the data, as you don't need it, it's fine to make the alternation non-capturing.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! and for explaing me regex!!

Comment: You're welcome. Checkout as well the PHP manual on the regex syntax and the other website I linked, they both explain the workings of regex which is especially useful if you run into an issue or before you write the pattern.